# Is WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy common to all applications running in the browser?

Tags: proxy, webproxy

Due to some reasons (mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68350282/how-to-connect-to-azure-service-bus-topic-through-proxy-c)), To handle the proxy in our web application, I have assigned the user-defined proxy values to `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy`.

Code:

```
var proxy = new WebProxy(data.ProxyUri);
proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(data.ProxyUsername, data.ProxyPassword);
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = proxy;
```

Since WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy is a Global HTTP Proxy, the assigned proxy values are reflected in other functionalities in our application. In regard to this, I am having a doubt whether the `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` property is common to a particular single application or all applications running in the same browser(or hosted in IIS)? Because I don't want to use this approach if affects/changes the default proxy of other applications.